# Is there a VLOOKUP function available for updating fields in a record?

Tags: lookup, field-update, recursion

Is there a non-apex way of updating a Boolean field on a record based on a comparison of values of a different field of all (or a filtered selection) the records in the table (object) to which the record belongs?

For example,
I have an custom object "Object__c" with two fields, one field stores a numeric value "Cost__c", another field is boolean and is called "Cheapest".
The table is populated with the following records:

UID: 001 Cost__c: 10.00

UID: 002 Cost__c: 100.00

UID: 003 Cost__c: 10.00

The default value for records for field "Cheapest__c" is FALSE

When record UID:001 is added to the table and is the first record added, "Cheapest__c" is set to True

When record UID:002 is added, the field "Cheapest__c" on that record remains to FALSE

When the next record (UID: 003) is added the field "Cheapest__c" is set to "TRUE" on both records UID: 10 and UID:30

Comment: can you elaborate the use case?

Comment: Sounds to me like a trigger would be the right tool for the job here. Can you expand on the reasons why you don't want to use Apex?

Comment: who'd want to use Apex wif there is a config option?

Comment: Who'd want to use a hammer to drive a nail when you have a perfectly good screwdriver handle? My point being that Apex is the proper tool (a hammer) for the job you are describing (driving a nail).

Comment: You can build a Process Builder for this, but it won't be "bulkified"; you may be limited on how many records you can update in bulk. Apex Code is the best option, but not the only option, if you're willing to accept the possible limitations.

Comment: @DerekF thx but I might want to use "no more nails" instead, see where I'm going with this?...

Comment: @sfdcfox thx for your reply, I'll look more into PB and hopefully post the answer following.

Comment: @Bartley I understand what you're getting at, you don't want to use Apex. I'll say it for a third time. It doesn't matter if you don't want to use it, Apex is the proper tool for the job here (in my opinion). The simple question that I've been asking you is _why don't you want to use Apex_?.  There may be other solutions (as sfdcfox has pointed out), but if there isn't a reason to avoid Apex other than "I just don't want to use it", then you're doing a disservice to your client (be they internal or external). If there is no client involved, and you're trying to challenge yourself, just say so.